# retrieve facebook like box dynamically

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins

I am creating a web app, similar to the like box code from Facebook: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/.

When users paste it in web application they should be able to get the like box including feeds if they have selected the stream, while generating the like box code.

I have used following code to do this; but the problem is I am not able to retrieve the pictures of the users who liked the page.

How do I retrieve their profile information?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Facebook Feeds</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getPage()
{
    var getCont=document.getElementById("txarea").value;
    document.getElementById("getContent").innerHTML=getCont;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<input type="text" id="txarea" />
<input type="button" id="fbBtnClick" value="Click" onclick="getPage();"></input>
<div id="getContent">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have tested this out and the following seems to be the problem:

> The height of the iframe is being set to **427px by default** the pictures are loading but are hidden becuase the height of the iframe is not long enough
>
> By default facebook gives the following:
>
> `<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fplatform&amp;width=292&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true&amp;`**height=427**`" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px;` **height:427px**;`" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>`
>
> Changing that too:
>
> `<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fplatform&amp;width=292&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true&amp;`**height=567**`" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px;`**height:567px**;`" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>`

Will show the pictures.. So I think you will have to take input from your users and then change the height then set it.